# Android - Socket.io not connecting

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, socket.io

I use Java and Socket.IO for the connection to my server, but i'm trying to connect nodejs server from android client side but connection not success.. (onConnectError) I tried all solutions, but I don't know how is my problem.

My server codes(server.js);

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const path = require('path');
    const server = require('http').createServer(app);
    const io = require('socket.io')(server);
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    
    server.listen(port, () => {
      console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
    });
    
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    
    
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      let addedUser = false;
      console.log('connection success');
    
    
      socket.on('example', (data) => {
        socket.emit('example', 'example');
        console.log('example');
      });
    
      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    
        console.log('disconnecting');
    
      });
    });
```

In java side, i use internet and http permission for manifest.

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"...
```

My java codes;

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

  public static Socket mSocket; {
    try {
      mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.35:3000");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
    mSocket.connect();
  }

  private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object...args) {
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect to NodeJS server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
      });
    }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    mSocket.disconnect();
    mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
    mSocket.off(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to use `ws://192.168.1.35:3000"`.
so change this

```
  public static Socket mSocket; {
    try {
      mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.35:3000");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

to this

```
  public static Socket mSocket; {
    try {
      mSocket = IO.socket("ws://192.168.1.35:3000");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you please comment your code and remove the link of the vedio

Comment: was my first answer, and it said i should give sources xD, so thats what i did